# using interpolation in angular on two different class object of the same type behaves like they are the same object

Tags: angular

I was following a tutorial on angular (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2) and decided to do something differently. Using the interpolation directive on two different class object of the same type works like they are they are the same object!

from the tutorial everything within the repeat directive *ngFor won't show because When the app starts, because the selectedCorper is undefined by design.

Binding expressions in the template that refer to properties of selectedCorper — expressions like {{selectedCorper.name}} — must fail because there is no selected corper.

but object 'corper' {{ corper.firstname | uppercase}} should still display because it isn't object selectedCorper

I tried changing the variable names and even the object type

```
// corper.component.html
<p>
  It works! This is {{ corper.firstname | uppercase }}
</p>

<h2>Some corpers</h2>
<ul class="corpers">
  <li *ngFor="let corper of corpers" (click)="onSelect(corper)" 
[class.selected]="corper === selectedCorper">
    <span class="badge">{{corper.spa}}</span> {{corper.firstname}}
  </li>
</ul>

<div > // removed the *ngIf="selectedCorper" directive
  <h4>
    the selected corper id is {{ selectedCorper.id }}, firstname {{ 
selectedCorper.firstname }}
  </h4>

  <div>
    <label for="firstname">
      name:
    </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedCorper.firstname" name="firstname" 
placeholder="selected corper's firstname">
  </div>
</div>
//-- end of corper.component.html

   // corper.component.ts
export class CorperComponent implements OnInit {

  mysql: mysql;

  corper: Corper = {
    ...
  };

  corpers = CORPERS;

  selectedCorper: Corper;

  onSelect(corper: Corper): void {
    this.selectedCorper = corper;
    console.log('WE PRESENT: the clicked/selected corper', corper);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I expected
    {{ corper.firstname | uppercase }}
to display results and not be undefined when the app starts

Comment: try initialize the variable inside constructor. for example:  this.corper = { firstname: 'test' };   in your code, corper is not initialized properly.

Comment: _I expected {{ corper.firstname | uppercase }} to display results and not be undefined_ in your code you havent setted the `firstname` property of that object

Comment: I think you should continue through the tour of heroes, maybe once you complete it you will be able to solve your issue.